# No longer able to open designer on my .NET Core3 WPF form

Tags: .net, wpf, visual-studio-2019

I have been writing a simple WPF app on VS2019 and .NET Core 3 since a few weeks ago.
Today (for other reasons) I had to try uninstalling/reinstalling Core3 runtime and SDK. Since sorting that problem I've found that I can no longer open the form designer. The app still builds and runs fine.
I know Core 3 is still pre-release [MS - please get on with it?], but it WAS working, and now isn't. I've tried Preview 9 and also re-tried Preview 6 (which is what I had before today).
Is there some magic extra setting that I've lost somewhere in the course of the day? As I say, it used to work, and it still build/runs.
:S

Comment: The error (can't I upload a pic of the popup here??) is along the lines of
WpfSurface failed to load the dll hostfxr.dll Result 0x800700C1

Answer (score 0):

I tried [creating a WPF core 3.0 project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/wpf#create-a-new-sdk-project) and uninstall/reinstall the [Core3 runtime and SDK](https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/release-notes/3.0/preview/3.0.0-preview9-download.md).

Then, I can open the form designer. There is no problem with my visual studio 2019 -16.2.3

So, I'm not sure why you get the error message. It may be cause by the .net core or you can try to repair the Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to fix this this morning, simply be deleting the obj and bin directories. I guess something that the Designer needed had got corrupted somehow